# What does my recruiter want to know when they ask for "availability at the earliest opportunity"?

Tags: interviewing, employment

So a recruiter emails me asking me for my availability and provides me with details of the interview which involves a test. I tell the recruiter that I am able to attend the interview on so and so day at so and so time.

the recruiter then copy and pastes the same email she had sent me again but changes it a little bit. she confirms the availability date and then also asks for my 'availability at the earliest opportunity' again.

I don't understand she had just confirmed the date and time and now asks the same question again.

Is she trying to ask for my notice period?

Comment: I'd guess she's processing lots of candidates and just made a mistake. Ask her? If she did want to know your notice period she'd probably just ask directly because it is a reasonable thing for her to need to know. And / or trying to get you hired as fast as possible, because that's when she gets paid.

Comment: We can only speculate what the recruiter means. Just reply and ask for clarification.

Comment: They are asking if granted the opportunity, when can you start.

Comment: having one day free to interview is not the same as having every workday free to work, is it?

Comment: @Dandavis I don't understand your comment

Comment: @JoeStrazzere I am only available on that particular day and have expressed that to her so i dont understand why shes asking for an earlier date.

Comment: my impression is that she asked you when you could interview, you answered, and now she's asking when you can start working. I don't get the confusion, but then again, i'm working 2nd-hand here...

Comment: @dandavis Oh i understand. I wasn't sure if she was asking for a notice period/when i could start so I thought id ask you all. My brain is tired today lol

Answer (score 6):

When a company wants to hire people, they are interested in two dates:

- When are they available for an interview?
- When can they start working for us?

So asking from which date on you are available to start working is a legitimate question.